# Apache POI autoSizeColumn() is not working

Tags: java

I've created an excel sheet using apache poi library and tried so much to change column width with respect to the content length by using autoSizeColumn() method, but no luck. I've used poi 2.5.1 and jdk 1.6. This is my code segment.

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 8; columnIndex++) {
 sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
}
```

I've used this code segment after inserting data to the excel sheet. The error message said that "cannot find symbol"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line is throwing the error

Comment: Second line. It says autoSizeColumn() method cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Apache POI (2.5.1) is quite old (released 2004-02-29) and for that version, the `Sheet` interface doesn't have the `autoSizeColumn` method.  For most open source projects, the [documentation on the web](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/) is usually for the current stable release, which for POI is currently 3.9 (released 2012-12-03).

You can [get source & documentation for your version of POI](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/poi/release/src/), but consider upgrading your version of POI - the latest version works with Java 1.6.