# APACHE POI autoSizeColumn with useMergedCells too slow

Tags: java, excel, performance, apache-poi

I try to apply autoSizeColumn on an Excel sheet. I'm using POI 3.10.1.
I apply autoSizeColumn at the end but the problem is than the process is too slow/long anyway: 
On the sheet I've approximately 1000 lines and 20 columns... After 5 hours, I kill the process ...
I don't understand what is taking so long, 1000 lines and 20 columns doesn't appear so huge: Did I miss something? (nb: on a smaller file, it's working)
My simplified code below:

```
    Workbook vWorkbook = getWorkbook();

    Sheet vSheet = vWorkbook.createSheet("sheet");
    CreationHelper vHelper = vWorkbook.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawing = vSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    Set<CellRangeAddress> vRegions = new HashSet<CellRangeAddress>();

    //Parcours des lignes du document
    MatrixDocument vMatrixDocument = getMatrixDocument();
    List<MatrixRow> vListMatrixRows = vMatrixDocument.getRows();
    int maxColNb = 0;

    //Parcours des lignes de la grille.
    for (MatrixRow vMatrixRow : vListMatrixRows)
    {
        //(...)
        //create cells 
        //(...)
    }

    initColSpan(vListMatrixRows, vRegions);

    //Gestion des colSpan et des RowSpan
    for (CellRangeAddress vRegion : vRegions)
    {
        vSheet.addMergedRegion(vRegion);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxColNb; ++i)
    {
        vSheet.autoSizeColumn(i, true);//Here the problem. spent more than 5 hour for 1000 lines and 20 columns
    }
```

I've already read threads below :

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943493/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-resizes-incorrectly

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740100/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-not-working-right

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366606/autosizecolumn-performance-effect-in-apache-poi

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984785/a-poi-related-code-block-running-dead-slow

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564045/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-behaving-weird

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456474/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-is-not-working

But none solve my issue.
Any idea ?
PS : I tried to upload an example image of the Excel file but I don't find how to upload it.

Comment: What happens if you try with Apache POI 3.12?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I didn't try with POI 3.12. Did you seen any correction about this issue? As soon as possible I will try it.

Comment: The [POI changelog is here](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), there's a lot of fixes mentioned since 3.10!

Comment: I tried POI 3.12. Not better.

Answer (score 0):

Even after using Apache POI 3.12, I was facing the same issue for auto-sizing. Also auto-size doesn't work in Unix/Linux.
What I learnt from various forums is this:
1.You can try is using the SXSSF API, usually works much faster. 
2. If not, then go for setColumnWidth method(I know its literally manual work for 20 columns)

Comment: Autosizing does work just fine on Linux! You can run the Apache POI unit tests and see for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was only use Autosize on the last Excel line, like this:

```
if (i >= abaExcel.Itens.Count)
    sheet.AutoSizeColumn(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because merged regions cannot overlap without producing a corrupt document, POI may be checking the list of merged regions on a sheet for potential intersections before adding a merged region. This gives O(N) behavior for adding one region instead of the expected O(1).

1. **addMergedRegion** - with  checking but slow
2. **addMergedRegionUnsafe** - without  checking but fast

Documentation: [read more about addMergedRegionUnsafe(...)](https://poi-apache-org.translate.goog/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=wapp)